# How to create a multiplechoice form with models queryset?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

The goal of this application is to let users select their favourite fonts using checkboxes and use the selected fonts somewhere else.

The thing is that, all the fonts are entered through the Admin panel by the admin, so the form should be able to get it from there.

This is what I thought doing :

**forms.py**

```
class ContactForm1(forms.ModelForm):
    choice = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=""" Get my models title as choice """, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())

    class Meta:
        model = ImageCheckView
        fields = ['title', 'choice']
...
```

**models.py**

```
class ImageCheckView(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    ...
```

What it will have to look like :

[image]

(I want to keep the selected options so I can use it somewhere else.)

How can I achieve the following ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution, I can create a new checkbox field on my forms and pass the object choices like this :

```
checkbox = forms.MultipleChoiceField(ImageCheckView.objects.all(), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
```